# How can I change the line height in the code cell of a jupyter notebook

Tags: html, css, jupyter-notebook

The space difference between 2 lines of code in my jupyter notebook is too much. I want to reduce it.

I checked out the `custom.css` file inside the custom folder in my `.Jupyter` directory, but I have no experience with CSS. I'm confused between so many options to change which one. Is it possible to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS, the distance between lines is defined as line-height. I'm not entirely sure how this will apply to you as i have never used Jupyter, but if it works from a CSS stylesheet you could use:

```
*{
    line-height:10px; // Tweak till happy
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though it did not specifically solved my problem, at least I got to tweak among the many line-height values that were in my custom.css file.

Answer (score 1):

In that custom.css file try to insert the following:

```
* { line-height: 140%; }
```

That's a line height parameter which makes the distance from one baseline (= the line on which the letters are put) to the next being 1.4 time the height of the maximum space that is used for letters.

Change that value until you find one that's convenient (120%, 160%, whatever)

The `*` character at the beginning makes that apply to *all* lines in the whole document. If headers and similar look okay and you only want to change the line height for "regular" text, write `p` instead of `*`, which will apply to all paragraphs, like

```
p { line-height: 140%; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

browser always load CSS which it see till the end of page load, If you want to edit something from your page but you want to create custom.css for that so linked that CSS on HTML page after Jupytor.css. After that Everything you will edit will be displayed in your page. Still explain your question more nicely if you are not achieving your goal. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the space difference between 2 lines of code by tweaking the line-height part in the following code. It is inside the `custom.css` file inside the `~/jupyter/custom` directory.

```
div.CodeMirror pre {line-height: 1.1 !important;}
```